# Ruby on Rails Merit gem with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, merit-gem

I'm trying to use the Merit gem with Devise, such that if the user fills in the Biography field in the Devise form, then they would be awarded a badge.

However, when I use it, it says

```
undefined method `biography' for true:TrueClass
```

Here's the part that's giving me the error:

**/models/merit/badge_rules.rb**

```
grant_on 'registrations#update', badge: 'autobiographer', temporary: true do |user|
  user.biography.present?
end
```

Why does it think that *user* is of the TrueClass?
**/views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb**

```
<h2>Edit <%= resource_name.to_s.humanize %></h2>
<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put, :class => 'form-vertical' }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= display_base_errors resource %>
  <%= f.input :first_name, :required => true, :autofocus => true %>
  <%= f.input :last_name, :required => true %>
  <%= f.input :username, :required => true %>
  <%= f.input :email, :required => true %>
  <%= f.input :biography %>
  <%= f.input :password, :autocomplete => "off", :hint => "leave it blank if you don't want to change it", :required => false %>
  <%= f.input :password_confirmation, :required => false %>
  <%= f.input :current_password, :hint => "we need your current password to confirm your changes", :required => true %>
  <%= f.button :submit, 'Update', :class => 'btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
<h3>Cancel my account</h3>
<p>Unhappy? <%= link_to "Cancel my account", registration_path(resource_name), :data => { :confirm => "Are you sure?" }, :method => :delete %>.</p>
<%= link_to "Back", :back %>
```

**merit.rb**

```
# Create application badges (uses https://github.com/norman/ambry)
badges = [
{id: 1,name: 'just-registered',image:"/images/registered.png",custom_fields:"Registered for an account"},
{id: 2,name: 'verified-user',image:"/images/verified-user.png",custom_fields:"Verified as a valid user" },
{id: 3,name: 'first-image',image:"/images/registered.png",custom_fields:"Uploaded first profile picture"},
{id: 4,name: 'first_vote',image:"/images/vote.png",custom_fields:"Voted for your first professor"},
{id: 5,name: 'autobiographer',image:"/images/biography.png",custom_fields:"Wrote a biography about yourself."}
]
badges.each do |badge|
  Merit::Badge.create!(badge)
end
```

Comment: Not sure why, but shouldn't the badges be created in the initalizer? docs: "Create badges in `config/initializers/merit.rb`"

Comment: @flynfish Sorry about that, mistype. I had actually put that code in the merit.rb file, I just wrote it wrong in the question. I updated the post.

Answer (score 2):

merit needs an instance variable that Devise Controllers don't instantiate. You need to do so, as described in: https://github.com/merit-gem/merit/wiki/How-to-grant-badges-on-user-using-Devise

Answer (score 0):

I know Devise is great for setting up user account management with just a few keystrokes, but it ends up being hard to integrate with other gems and features. From my experience, it's worth the extra time in the beginning to setup user authentication yourself like following Michael Hartl's example http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book. There were definite problems using Merit with Devise's generated models like User, but none after using Hartl's.